# Can anyone tell me the meaning of "overcorrected"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is there a word "overcorrected"? Couldn't find any.

Comment: I don't know where you looked (you don't say), but, you can find it in [dictionaries](https://onelook.com/?w=overcorrect&ls=a).

Comment: @J.R. perhaps we should have pointed out "overcorrected" is the past-tense conjugation of "overcorrect"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. For example, if a driver starts to skid, they may turn the steering wheel to correct the skid, or they may turn the wheel too far, which would be an overcorrection, leading to 'fish tailing'.

Similar examples can be found for anything mechanical.